# Stress testing jenkins master using jmeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am trying to stress test my jenkins infrastructure using jmeter. I have created a Jmeter TestPlan which uses HTTPRequest component of jmeter to trigger the jenkins builds using jenkins rest api. The idea is to trigger a large number of builds and monitor the System health. when I run the jmeter test plan for single thread it works fine, but when I run it with multiple threads each HTTPrequest to trigger the jenkins build should be run for each thread... but it runs only once i.e. each build is triggered only once on jenkins (no matter what is the thread count). In Jmeter test results, it shows that the HTTPRequest is successful for all the threads.. but on Jenkins the build seems to be triggered only for 1 thread group.

Comment: can you share jmeter script ?

Answer (score 1):

Well-behaved JMeter test must represent real system usage, if you want to simulate user clicking Jenkins "Build Now" button you need to send request like:

> http://jenkins_host:port/job/jobname/build?**delay=0sec**

this `delay=0sec` parameter is uber important as if you don't have it only first request will trigger the job, with this parameter you will have either as many concurrent jobs as available [executors](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/216456477-What-is-a-Jenkins-Executor-and-how-can-I-best-utilize-my-executors):

[image]

If there are not enough executors to serve all the jobs, the jobs will be put into [queue](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jqs-monitoring/)

You can use [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/) for monitoring Jenkins node health (CPU, RAM, JVM metrics, etc.)